# What are the equivalent functions that I should use for HTTP handling?

Tags: 8

Looking at the functions listed in the [HTTP handling page for Drupal 7](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/group/http_handling/7.x), I noticed that the following functions don't exist anymore in Drupal 8. (The links are for the Drupal 7 documentation pages, where the links to the Drupal 8 documentation for those functions are missing.)

- [drupal_access_denied()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_access_denied/7)
- [drupal_get_query_array()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_query_array/7)
- [drupal_goto()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7)
- [drupal_http_request()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7)
- [drupal_not_found()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_not_found/7)
- [drupal_site_offline()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_site_offline/7)

What functions/methods should I instead use in Drupal 8?

Comment: This is question is part of a serie of questions about the differences between Drupal 7 and Drupal 8.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These are the functions/methods/classes that should be used in Drupal 8.6.x code.

- `drupal_access_denied()` has been replaced from the [AccessDeniedHttpException](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-kernel%21Exception%21AccessDeniedHttpException.php/class/AccessDeniedHttpException/8.6.x) class. Page callbacks that need to return the Access Denied error should used code similar to the following one.

  ```
  // system_batch_page()
  public function batchPage(Request $request) {
    require_once $this->root . '/core/includes/batch.inc';
    $output = _batch_page($request);
    if ($output === FALSE) {
      throw new AccessDeniedHttpException();
    }
    elseif ($output instanceof Response) {
      return $output;
    }
    elseif (isset($output)) {
      $title = isset($output['#title']) ? $output['#title'] : NULL;
      $page = [
        '#type' => 'page',
        '#title' => $title,
        '#show_messages' => FALSE,
        'content' => $output,
      ];

      // Also inject title as a page header (if available).
      if ($title) {
        $page['header'] = [
          '#type' => 'page_title',
          '#title' => $title,
        ];
      }
      return $page;
    }
  }
  ```
- Instead of `drupal_get_query_array()` there is [`parse_query()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21guzzlehttp%21psr7%21src%21functions.php/function/parse_query/8.6.x) (a function in the `GuzzleHttp\Psr7` namespace), which is part of Guzzle.
- `drupal_goto()` has been replaced from the [`RedirectResponse`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21RedirectResponse.php/class/RedirectResponse/8.6.x) class. Page callbacks that need to redirect users should use code similar to the following one. (Notice that form submission handlers should not use this class.)

  ```
  // AddSectionController::build()
  public function build(SectionStorageInterface $section_storage, $delta, $plugin_id) {
    $section_storage
      ->insertSection($delta, new Section($plugin_id));
    $this->layoutTempstoreRepository
      ->set($section_storage);
    if ($this->isAjax()) {
      return $this->rebuildAndClose($section_storage);
    }
    else {
      $url = $section_storage->getLayoutBuilderUrl();
      return new RedirectResponse($url->setAbsolute()->toString());
    }
  }
  ```
- `drupal_http_request()` has been replaced from a Drupal 8 service that implements the [ClientInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21guzzlehttp%21guzzle%21src%21ClientInterface.php/interface/ClientInterface/8.6.x) interface. Drupal 8 code should be similar to the following one.

  ```
  // system_retrieve_file()
  try {
    $data = (string) \Drupal::httpClient()->get($url)->getBody();
    $local = $managed ? file_save_data($data, $path, $replace) : file_unmanaged_save_data($data, $path, $replace);
  } catch (RequestException $exception) {
    \Drupal::messenger()->addError(t('Failed to fetch file due to error "%error"', ['%error' => $exception->getMessage()]));
    return FALSE;
  }
  ```
- `drupal_not_found()` has been replaced from the [NotFoundHttpException](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-kernel%21Exception%21NotFoundHttpException.php/class/NotFoundHttpException/8.6.x) class. Page callbacks should use code similar to the following one.

  ```
  // BookController::bookExport()
  public function bookExport($type, NodeInterface $node) {
    $method = 'bookExport' . Container::camelize($type);

    // @todo Convert the custom export functionality to serializer.
    if (!method_exists($this->bookExport, $method)) {
      $this->messenger()->addStatus(t('Unknown export format.'));
      throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    }
    $exported_book = $this->bookExport->{$method}($node);
    return new Response($this->renderer->renderRoot($exported_book));
  }
  ```
- `drupal_site_offline()` should be replaced by an event subscriber, similar to the following one.

  ```
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['onKernelRequestMaintenance', 30];
    $events[KernelEvents::EXCEPTION][] = ['onKernelRequestMaintenance'];
    return $events;
  }

  public function onKernelRequestMaintenance(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $route_match = RouteMatch::createFromRequest($request);
    if ($this->maintenanceMode->applies($route_match)) {
      // Don't cache maintenance mode pages.
      \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
      if (!$this->maintenanceMode->exempt($this->account)) {
        // Deliver the 503 page if the site is in maintenance mode and the
        // logged in user is not allowed to bypass it.
        // If the request format is not 'html' then show default maintenance
        // mode page else show a text/plain page with maintenance message.
        if ($request->getRequestFormat() !== 'html') {
          $response = new Response($this->getSiteMaintenanceMessage(), %03, ['Content-Type' => 'text/plain']);
          $event->setResponse($response);
          return;
        }
        drupal_maintenance_theme();
        $response = $this->bareHtmlPageRenderer->renderBarePage([          '#markup' => $this->getSiteMaintenanceMessage()], $this->t('Site under maintenance'), 'maintenance_page');
        $response->setStatusCode(503);
        $event->setResponse($response);
      }
      else {
        // Display a message if the logged in user has access to the site in
        // maintenance mode. However, suppress it on the maintenance mode
        // settings page.
        if ($route_match->getRouteName() != 'system.site_maintenance_mode') {
          if ($this->account->hasPermission('administer site configuration')) {
            $this->messenger->addMessage($this
        ->t('Operating in maintenance mode. <a href=":url">Go online.</a>', [':url' => $this->urlGenerator->generate('system.site_maintenance_mode')]), 'status', FALSE);
          }
          else {
            $this->messenger->addMessage($this->t('Operating in maintenance mode.'), 'status', FALSE);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ```

  - `drupal_encode_path()` has been replaced by [`UrlHelper::encodePath()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21UrlHelper.php/function/UrlHelper%3A%3AencodePath/8.6.x)
  - `drupal_get_query_parameters()` has been replaced by `UrlHelper::filterQueryParameters()`
  - `drupal_http_build_query()` has been replaced by [`UrlHelper::buildQuery()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21UrlHelper.php/function/UrlHelper%3A%3AbuildQuery/8.6.x), which will be removed once Drupal core requires at least PHP 5.4 (At that point, it will be possible to directly use  [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/http_build_query).)
  - `drupal_parse_url()` has been replaced by [`UrlHelper::parse()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21UrlHelper.php/function/UrlHelper%3A%3Aparse/8.6.x)

Notice that, compared with earlier Drupal versions, there are some important changes. For example, some methods that were in the `Url` class has been moved in the `UrlHelper` class; some of the Guzzle classes aren't used anymore.

Comment: Some of the API links are dead.

Comment: It's probable those functions have been removed from Drupal core. I will check which links are dead and remove them.

Comment: It also seem some of the links aren't anymore valid, but the class/function/method still exists. They just change the link format, or the class/function/method has been moved to a different file.